# What is formula that can be used to convert "9am to 630pm" time format to military time in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble getting the correct formula to change the value to military time. Formula or conditional formatting isn't working

Comment: What formula did you try? Post that to your post. What result do you expect. Show in excel sheet.

Comment: "9am to 630pm" is a string containing 2 times.  You cannot convert this to military time without additional parsing of the string into different parts first which you likely cannot do without the help of VBA

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell and select Format cells option then click on Number menu tab option, select Time in Category column then select 13:30 in Type box. now we can type/paste the time in that formatted cell for example 05:30:10 PM then that cell automatically shows the answer with 17:30.Cell format option. Please see the image in the below link.

[Image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YywYZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is about formatting, not a formula.
If you want to show the two formats in column A and column B then the formula is just in B2, `=A2`

Then in B2, do Right Click | Format Cells |  Number | Custom
Try the different formats already there - most relevant for you is that if there is an AM/PM it will show 12 hour version; otherwise it will show 24-hour version.